# How to output windows Alt keycodes in a C# console app

Tags: c#, key, alt, console.writeline

How can I output Windows Alt key codes to the console in a C# console app using Console.WriteLine()?

I would like to output characters such as those used for creating boxes.
I can do so manually in a command prompt by holding alt and typing in the appropriate number such as Alt+205, Alt+187, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose the easiest way would be to include them directly in your string literals within your source code:

```
Console.WriteLine("═╗");
```

Comment: Accepted, thank you. I can't believe this never occurred to me! I was too busy thinking in terms of ASCII codes to even consider doing the obvious!

Comment: Be careful that [Alt codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code) do not correspond to [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII); in fact, `═` and `╗` are not even valid ASCII characters (whichever way you specify them), since ASCII values only range from 0 to 127.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:  I'm sorry - my answer is incorrect.  ASCII.GetChars will not work for extended ASCII characters.  Thanks to Douglas for correcting me.

---

I think Douglas's answer is the most direct, but you could also get the character based on the value directly using something like this:

> char[] characters = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(new byte[]
>   {65});

For whatever ASCII code you wanted.

Comment: Thanks, this may be useful for the future.

Comment: This answer is technically incorrect for the characters that the OP requires; `═` and `╗` cannot be represented in ASCII. The closest you can get is by replacing `Encoding.ASCII` with `Encoding.GetEncoding(437)`, but that will not always work since the code page may be absent from the machine.