# How do I find a character matching my alt code

Tags: c#, wpf

When I type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> I get back ☺
I would like some magic way in code to get the ☺ character in a string.

Something like this:

```
string smiley = AltCodes.GetAltCodeCharacter(1).ToString();

// Display the Smiley
richTextBoxHappy.Text = smiley;
```

Then in the rich text box there should be this: `☺`

Comment: Alt+1 does not mean the same thing in every program, so where ever you are getting that character from is specific to that program.  If you know the unicode for the character though you can do something like `"\u1F642"` to get that character.

Comment: if you know the code, you can use format `&#`+ code, like this: `&#200`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to output windows Alt keycodes in a C# console app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10870533/how-to-output-windows-alt-keycodes-in-a-c-sharp-console-app)

Comment: @Cid I doubt it since the question is tagged with WPF and clearly the OP is trying to put the character into a textbox.

Comment: @juharr `string smiley = "☺"` ?

Comment: probably relevant: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: @Cid Yes, just copy and pasting the character into code would also work.  The main point though is that there is no Alt+1 to smiley face mapping unless they create one themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Unicode Table (Decimal)](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode-decimal.html) to find out your code, then use it like this for example:

```
int i = 9786;
textBoxHappy.Text = ((char)i).ToString();
```

Result image:

[image]

### Edit

Of course you can create your custom mapping, for example some `Dictionary<string, int>` (or any custom type you want), and add codes to it like `{ "smiley", 9786 }`, then use it `altCode["smiley"]`.

### Update

Or use `enum` for that:

```
enum AltCodes
{
    Smiley = 9786,
    NextSmiley = 9787
}
```

and use it like:

```
textBoxHappy.Text = ((char)AltCodes.Smiley).ToString();
```

You can even create your custom decoder, then write your alt code (by holding alt and typing numbers) inside wpf `TextBox`, click *"Decode"* and get your code values to `int[]` for example:

```
private int[] DecodeCharCode(string str) =>
    DecodeCharCode(str.ToArray());


private int[] DecodeCharCode(char[] chars)
{
    int[] result = new int[chars.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = (int)chars[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

and usage (click event or command):

```
int[] decodedCodes = DecodeCharCode(decodingText.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks ☺
:) This link with the unicode table is really helpful

Answer (score 1):

[There is a finite number of these.](https://www.alt-codes.net) You can just create a `Dictionary<int, string>` to store all these:

```
IReadOnlyDictionary<int, string> altCodes = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
    {1, "☺"},
    {2, "\U0000263B"},
    // and so on...
};
```

And access it like so:

```
altCodes[1]
```